# Specific Breslov Nusach

Tags: nusach-sefard, nusach-ari, breslov

I understand that traditionally Breslov has not taken Nusach HaTefillah as seriously as other Chassidic groups when it comes to identifying the Sha'ar HaKollel. Although most Breslovers daven Nusach Sefard, through the teachings of Rebbe Nachman the concept of Sha'ar HaKollel has been interpreted as attachment to the Tzaddik, instead of an actual nusach.

(There is an undocumented oral tradition about Rebbe Nachman saying that if he had grown up davening Nusach Ashkenaz he would have continued in that nusach. In other words, he would not have switched over to Nusach Sefard.)

But like any Chassidic group, there are certain additions/omissions to the "standard" Nusach Sefard siddurim on the market these days that distinguish a Chassidic dynasty from others. For instance, Lubavitch has its own version of Nusach Sefard which was compiled by the Ba'al HaTanya in attempt to form a "true" Nusach Ari (if such a thing is possible).  My question is: are there any details that distinguish the nusach of Breslov from a standard Nusach Sefard?

As an example for what I mean, is "asher nasan lasechvi" said or is "hanosein lasechvi" said? Is "tze'etza'einu v'tze'etza'ei" added in the Birkos HaTorah? Do Breslovers say "mashiv haruach umorid hatal" or just "morid hatal"? I'm sure you get what I mean by now.

Anyway, I would be interested in knowing the ins-and-outs of Breslov nusach. In addition, does anyone know any online resources that have recordings of Breslover nusach, as in niggunim used by the chazzan in shul for the tefillos?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75328/759

Comment: @DoubleAA - Yeah I asked that question a while back. Even if Chut Shel Chesed Yeshiva uses Siddur Tefillas Kol Peh, that doesn't mean they don't make changes to the "standard" nusach found therein.

Comment: It seems like the beginning of your question is potentially the answer. Which would seem to imply this is specific to a community and not Breslov as a whole

Comment: I recall seeing a breslov siddur that is made by a group of breslovers located in NY (I believe they from the same group who makes a large majority of the pamphlets you see around By Mohorosh.)

Comment: FWIW in relation to your comment to Double AA, Rademishel uses Siddur Kol Ya'akov, but adjusts certain girsaot based on their nusach. I've also heard that the Munkatcher siddur, composed by R' Eluzur Spira of Munkatch, was created based on an almost-critical study of the kitvei R' Yitzchak Luria available to him (which accounted presumably for the entirety of the corpus)

Comment: @Laser123 - I would be EXTREMELY interested in knowing more about that siddur.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Is the Rademishel shtiebel Breslov? And are you trying to say that the Munkatch siddur is used by a lot of Breslovers?

Comment: No, they're actually somehow connected to Sanz, I'm merely making a point to emphasise yours. I have no idea whether any Breslovers use the Munkatcher siddur.

Comment: this link is for breslov seforim and has in it a link for shachris and one for mincha/maariv... http://breslovbooks.com/pdf/

Comment: @Laser123 - wow thanks. after taking a closer look at it though it looks like just a normal sephardi nusach so unless the breslovers use the sephardi nusach then it's not technically breslov, just a sephardi siddur with some breslov additions.

Comment: @ezra I am not familiar with the sephardi nusachim. However, glancing through it I noticed some additions that seems to be specific to "na nach" breslovers that invoked praying in the merit of all tzadikim and specifically na nach etc Rav Nachmon ben Feiga

Comment: @Laser123 - Yes but there was also the Sephardi Adon Olam and no Tzur Yisroel before Shmoneh Esrei.

Comment: I think tzur yisrael is specific to nusach askenaz though? I use for example the chabad version of nusach arizal which doesn't have tzur yisroel before the amida. If you are right that think is in fact edut misrachi with some additions perhaps there is a community of breslov the are sephardi which confirms your original hypothesis

Comment: @Laser123 - There are lots of Sephardi Breslovers. And Tzur Yisroel is found in many Nusach Sfard siddurim too, but you're right when you say that the Chabad siddur doesn't have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only specific detail in nusach that I can think of for which the Rebbe made a particular point, was to say "melech yachid chei ha'olamim" in Yishtabach in order to mirror the text of "Baruch Sheamar."   I suppose there are some other points in davening with a very strong attribution to the Baal Shem Tov (in whose house the Rebbe grew up) for which many Breslovers are particular, like "hazan b’rachamav es hakol" in bentching.

As you indicated, there has always been a lack of emphasis on minhagim in Breslov, particularly in regards to nusach hatefillah.  Also, Breslov had long been regionalized with the Polish and the Russian/Ukrainian chassidim adhering to their local minhagim.  Furthermore, matters are "confused" by the fact that there were two or three different mesorahs that developed from Reb Noson’s talmidim.

A great number of the Breslov manhigim of the last 100 years were first generation Breslovers, in many cases literally finding a Tikkun Haklali or a Likutei Moharan in some corner of their yeshiva and feeling compelled to seek out a teacher in the Rebbe's derech.  Many felt no need to change their customs, while some took on their teachers'.

For what it’s worth, the Sternhartz/Kenig line has long been particular about recording their minhagim.   R’ Dovid Sears and R’ Dovid Zeitlin have done some excellent work in compiling these, with multiple articles in English available at http://breslovcenter.blogspot.com.

Here is one on R’ Gedaliah Kenig’s personal nusach:  http://breslovcenter.blogspot.com/2012/05/reb-gedaliahs-nusach-for-shemoneh-esreh.html.

Answer (score 2):

Mohorosh z"l (the Tzadik of yavnial) printed a siddur called "Sidur eis rotzon", and in a letter in his popular sefer (response) "Asher banachal" he states that this is exactly the nusach that Reb Nachmen of breslev used.

Comment: I have seen siddurim "im peirush eis rotzon" that were breslov. is this what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes dear, I am talking of this siddur.

Comment: Look what I found! https://books.google.co.il/books?id=_ehr31HOt50C&lpg=PT1&dq=%D7%9B%22%D7%A7+%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%22%D7%A9+%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%98%22%D7%90&lr=&pg=PP1&hl=en#v=onepage&q=%D7%9B%22%D7%A7%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%22%D7%A9%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%98%22%D7%90&f=false

Comment: and also http://www.breslev.co.il/store/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A2%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%A2%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%93/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D__%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D.aspx?id=11792&language=hebrew

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of the first bracha in Birkas Hamazon, the minhag of Rebbe Nachman was to recite "hazan b'rachamav es hakol", including the word "b'rachamav" to the usual nusach.